# Short link - WebView shouldoverride not working

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to display Facebook website in my app's `WebView` and trying to do some tricks with it..

Basically what I want to do is load the main url **https://m.facebook.com/home.php** in the `MainActivity` and after that every link which gets clicked should be passed to the second activity, let's call it `DisplayActivity`, and `MainActivity` shouldn't load it... So `MainActivity` holds only the main url...

**Problems:**

1. Facebook's internal URLs are like `/my/profile/` instead of `https://m.facebook.com/my/profile/`
2. `WebView`, as per Android Developers website, won't make callbacks to `onPageStarted`, `onPageFinished`, or `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` for these types of links
3. Can't use `loadDataWithBaseUrl` method to load url as I need to pass HTML code of the page everytime a new page is loaded and also because this can not determine if user is logged in or not so it will load login page of Facebook...

So is there a way to make `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method work?

Comment: `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` has been notoriously broken for awhile. (It works in some situations, but there are a lot of common ones when it doesn't.) There has been a Google bug report filed for it which hasn't been touched for years. Basically, don't rely on it.

Comment: @JonAdams that's a problem then... 
I may use the onProgressChanged method of ChromeClient but how to stop the webview from loading the url in it and getting the clicked url to pass in intent?